# Format some strings which are inside a dictionary

Tags: python, string, templates, dictionary, format

I would like to do something like the following, I don't know if it's possible:

```
d={
'error': ' Please insert a valid (%s) name'
'required': ' Please insert your (%s) name'
}

d1 = d % 'first'
d2 = d % 'last'
```

So basically I want something like a dictionary template. Is it a way to make this possible? It would be more elegant to do so and as well respect the DRY principle.

**Expected result**:

```
d1 == {'required': ' Please insert your (first) name',
       'error': ' Please insert a valid (first) name'}

d2 == {'required': ' Please insert your (last) name',
       'error': ' Please insert a valid (last) name'}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I need to create another 2 dictionaries (d1 and d2) starting from d

Comment: do you need d1 = Please insert a valid first name?

Comment: `d['error'] % "first"` --> `'Please insert a valid (first) name'`. I don't think it does what you expect.

Comment: I need what falsetru answered. And I think his method is the simplest way: to create a function

Comment: There's a comma missing in your dict template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about define a function that generate a dictionary?

```
>>> def make_msg_dict(part):
...     return {
...         'error': ' Please insert a valid (%s) name' % part,
...         'required': ' Please insert your (%s) name' % part,
...     }
...
>>> d1 = make_msg_dict('first')
>>> d2 = make_msg_dict('last')
>>> d1
{'required': ' Please insert your (first) name',
 'error': ' Please insert a valid (first) name'}
>>> d2
{'required': ' Please insert your (last) name',
 'error': ' Please insert a valid (last) name'}
```

Comment: @MihaiZamfir, I updated your question to make it clear what you want. (added an expected result)